# PHP - Pass parameter to function if object exists, otherwise default to null

Tags: php, formbuilder

I'm currently working on a form builder helper class in php, containing static methods that add fields of various types (addTextfield(), addBooleanField(), etc), with the aim of using one template for each object type, regardless of whether I'm adding a new object or editing an existing one.

The relevant part of the FormBuilder essentially does this:

```
class FormBuilder {
    public static function addTextField($name, $default_value){
        echo "<input type='text' name='{$name}' value='{$default_value}'>";
    }
}
```

And here's a dummy class to use as an example

```
class Team {
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $city;
}
```

So when editing an existing team, I'll have a `$team` variable to pass in the current values. If I'm adding a new team, obviously these values won't be set, and $team won't exist. I'm struggling to find an efficient way to pass in the current values. The only successful method I've found so far is:

```
<div>
    <span>Team Name</span>
    <?php FormBuilder::addTextField("name", (isset($team) ? $team->name: "")); ?>
</div>
<div>
    <span>City</span>
    <?php FormBuilder::addTextField("city", (isset($team) ? $team->city: "")); ?>
</div>
```

Some of these forms will get quite large, so adding `isset($item) ? $item->prop : ""` for each one isn't ideal.

There's also the option to define a `$defaults` array at the start of the template, dependent on whether the item exists, but again this leaves some room for error

Creating a dummy instance of the Team class isn't an option as the objects throw errors if a valid instance can't be found in the database.

I tried changing the param in the method to `&$default_value`, but this prevents me from passing in values directly, which I will need to do occasionally.

I feel like I may be asking too much of the code, but the aim is to repeat things as little as possible.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Take a look to [Symfony Forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html), it should help. It's based on mapping the class and you can also embed a form of a subclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about the following:

```
addTextFieldFromEntity($name, $entity = null, $entityField = null)
```

and then:

```
<?php FormBuilder::addTextFieldFromEntity("name", $team, "name"); ?>
```

Or something more complex:

```
class EntityWrapper
{
    private $entity;

    public static function init($entity)
    {
        return new EntityWrapper($entity);
    }

    public function __construct($entity)
    {
        $this->entity = $entity;
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        if (!is_null($this->entity)) {
            return '';
        }

        return $this->entity->$name;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
<?php FormBuilder::addTextField("name", EntityWrapper::init($team)->name); ?>
```

Comment: With the example I've given that would be fine, but the issue is, the properties can be nested and more complex than those I've given. For example there is a "game" class, which contains an array of the two teams. So when calling `$game->teams['home']->name`, if I'm not mistaken I'd have to rely on eval to parse it correctly

Comment: This is not related to the question, but to be honest I don't like much the design of your entities. It makes more sense to be able to instantiate a entity which is still not inserted to the database, i.e. there is no relation between that entity and the database.
It makes even more sense to use a frameworks which provides similar functionality instead implementing this by yourself.

Comment: To be completely honest, I think I'd dismissed that option without giving it enough consideration. As it stands, I've got a parent class with a magic method that populates properties from the database when required. It wouldn't be too much work to modify it, so that it only does so when the item already 'exists'. If I struggle, then I still have the EntityWrapper to use in the meantime. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

How about using the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern ?
Let that return empty values. If it is a new team you pass that null object instead.